# Recommendations for porting a C# WPF .NET 4.0 application to Mac OS X (Mono?)

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, macos, mono

I currently have a (non commercial) application created in MS Visual C# 4.5, using WPF and LINQ.

To make a future porting possible to Mac OS X, I have used the MVVM design pattern to split the logic and user interface.

I would like to know:
1) I know WPF is not supported by Mono. I use a lot of bindings. Is it possible to port this into WinForms (or another way that is supported by Mono) in a reasonably easy manner?

2) I guess all LINQ functionality has to be changed into for/foreach loops?

3) Are there other considerations or recommendations I can take into account or warn when porting it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most LINQ should work using Mono. Have no idea about WPF though.

Comment: MoMA is also a usefull tool here: http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA

Comment: WPF is not supported at all. To have nice interface you will need to use gtk# [Mono] (http://www.mono-project.com/Gui_Toolkits)

Comment: XWT is another option: http://github.com/mono/xwt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Silverligt runs on the Mac. If your application can be limited to what is possible in Silverlight the porting will be very easy because basically Silverlight is WPF in the browser. In the recently released Silverlight 5 you are able to access the entire local file system when running out-of-browser and you can also create multiple windows.

Comment: Thank you ... this seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, the Mono XWT cross platform Widget toolkit should do the trick - if (as of April 2012) you're willing to work with very fresh code.

XWT is similar to the SWT widget kit for Eclipse/Java in that it maps directly to the native OS's widgets for Mac-OSX, Linux, and Windows-WPF.  It differs in that it is based on the layout system and general API of the GTK-Sharp library used for much of the Mono tools stack (i.e. MonoDevelop, MonoDoc, Banshee, etc.)  According to the FOSDEM slides, XWT is intended as a replacement/addition to GTK-Sharp for the Mono project and Xamarin's use in MonoDevelop.  My guess is that they want to move MonoDevelop to appear to be more OS native and/or prettier that the GTK widget kit allows presently, possibly to bring their toolchain more towards parity with the Eclipse offerings.

At the time of the writing this answer, the XWT toolkit was still undergoing heavy development (particularly the Windows WPF version), but was reasonably functional on all three platforms.